# javascript grammar in antlr4

Tags: javascript, antlr4

I have used the following link for JavaScript grammar .

```
https://github.com/ftomassetti/antlr-web-example
```

However , when I use JavaScript's grammar(JavaScriptLexer.g4 and JavaScriptParser.g4) rather than grammar(todo.g4) , it shows a error when defined.

```
ATNDeserializer.js:171 Uncaught AADB8D7E-AEEF-4415-AD2B-8204D6CF042E
```

[image]

What is this error for ?

What do I do to use antlr and JavaScript grammar to create an intermediate code ?

My grammar files:

- JavaScriptLexer.g4
- JavaScriptParser.g4

https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/javascript/javascript

This is my code: index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>ANTLR on the Web</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/require.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
<div id="inputs">
<textarea id="code">
* play with antlr4
* write a tutorial
</textarea>
<br/>
<button id="parse">Parse</button>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

var antlr4 = require('antlr4/index');
var JavaScriptParser = require('./generated-parser/JavaScriptParser');
console.log("start");
document.getElementById("parse").addEventListener("click", function(){
    // var JavaScriptLexer = require('generated-parser/JavaScriptLexer');
    // var input = document.getElementById("code").value;
    // var chars = new antlr4.InputStream(input);
    // var lexer = new JavaScriptLexer.JavaScriptLexer(chars);
    // var tokens  = new antlr4.CommonTokenStream(lexer);
    // var parser = new JavaScriptParser.JavaScriptParser(tokens);
    // parser.buildParseTrees = true;
    // var tree = parser.program();
    // console.log("Parsed: "+ tree);
    // updateTree(tree, parser.ruleNames);
});
</script>
<div id="tree">
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Make sure you are generating the .js files with the Antlr 4.9.1 tool, and you using the corresponding 4.9.1 JS runtime. The Antlr runtime at https://github.com/ftomassetti/antlr-web-example/tree/master/static/antlr4 are for 4.5.2 https://github.com/ftomassetti/antlr-web-example/blob/master/static/antlr4/Recognizer.js#L48. You can tell if you look at the comments in the generated parser and lexer .js files. You might want to start with a straight forward Node app.

Comment: And, there is a [bug](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/issues/2003) in the grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@kaby76 essentially described the problem. You are using an old runtime. The error shows the UUID for the ["lexer action" feature](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Java/src/org/antlr/v4/runtime/atn/ATNDeserializer.java#L69). The ANTLR4 tool you used to generate your parser is newer than the runtime. Make sure the runtime matches the tool version (or is newer).

Comment: The problem was solved by using the same version runtime and antlr, but it gives the error [Maximum call stack size exceeded] when I use the command [var tree = parser.variableDeclaration();]. Why does this happen? I use the default antlr grammar.

Comment: The parser generated is a recursive descent parser. It can crash if the call stack gets too deep, usually because the rules in the grammar are recursive (the reason to use the `+` and `*` operators of EBNF instead). To solve this problem, you will need to debug your program. Try a small example that does parse and gradually add to it, and identify what parsing rules are involved.

Comment: @NourahmadKhosravi Ask this question separately. We need to look at your grammar for a more detailed answer.

Comment: @kaby76 Hi, I used a short term[if] and a brief rule [ifStatement] and worked . But when I use the longer term[if(] , it again gives error [Maximum call stack size exceeded] . Can grammar have problems?

Comment: @NourahmadKhosravi Try it in Node or a different browser. Make sure it's a 64-bit process. The grammar and generated JS code--with the change in grammars-v4/javascript/javascript/JavaScriptParser.g4 changed, "let" => "let_", Antlr 4.9.1--look okay.